# Android Custom View Flickering

Tags: android, view, surfaceview, flicker

I've been trying to solve my problem for a long time now.  However, I'm at a loss.  The problem is this:

1. I have a Custom Android View that I render 10 rectangles on(kind of
   like a bar chart all the same length, different color)
2. When updating one of the rectangles with different opacity, it
       doesn't change.  So I clear the Canvas.  But this causes a flicker,
       not all the time, but sometimes

What I've tried doing:

1. Render everything to an offscreen bitmap, then blting it, this still
   doesn't solve my issue
2. Use a SurfaceView and render in another thread
3. A combination of 1 and 2

In the end, I think the problem is that the background gets erased, but I don't want it to erase.  However, I can never get the new "pixels" to show up.  I also tried experimenting with different transfer modes like SRC, SRC_ATOP,  when I tried number 1, it helps, but does not get rid of the problem.

Does anyone have any guidance on what could be going wrong?  Or any other possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I have finally figured it out.  I don't have to clear the back ground, just temporarily change the paint mode to SRC.

```
context.paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
context.paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC));
context.canvas.drawPath(context.path, context.paint);
context.paint.setXfermode(null);
```